Stub/mock supabase storage methods
I'm trying to unit tests some custom implemented edge functions with supabase-js.
I'm using Deno and sinonjs for that.
For my edge function i've got multiple scenarios, for the first one I want to stub supabaseClient.storage.from method so it is rejected.
Here is the code:
edge function code
import 'https://deno.land/x/xhr@0.3.0/mod.ts';
import { supabaseAdmin } from '../_shared/supabaseAdmin.ts';
import { corsHeaders } from '../_shared/cors.ts';

Deno.serve(async (req) => {

    const { campaign_id, call_id, speaker, name } = await req.json()

    const { data, error } = await supabaseAdmin
        .storage
        .from('campaigns')
        .createSignedUrl(`${campaign_id}/calls/${call_id}/audios/${name}`, 60);
    
    if (error) {
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: error['message'] }), {
            status: error['status'],
            headers: { ...corsHeaders, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        })
    } else if (data) {
        // proceed with data
    }
});

test file
import 'https://deno.land/x/xhr@0.3.0/mod.ts';
import sinon from "npm:sinon";
import { assert, assertEquals } from "https://deno.land/std@0.108.0/testing/asserts.ts";
import { createClient, SupabaseClient } from 'https://esm.sh/@supabase/supabase-js@2.23.0'
import { StorageApiError } from 'https://esm.sh/@supabase/storage-js@2.5.4';

// Set up the configuration for the Supabase client
const supabaseUrl = Deno.env.get('SUPABASE_URL') ?? ''
const supabaseKey = Deno.env.get('SUPABASE_ANON_KEY') ?? ''
const options = {
  auth: {
    autoRefreshToken: false,
    persistSession: false,
    detectSessionInUrl: false,
  },
}

const supabaseAdmin: SupabaseClient = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey, options);

const testNoCampaigns = async () => {
  
  const stubFrom = sinon.stub(
    supabaseAdmin.storage,
    "from"
  ).rejects(new StorageApiError('Object not found', 404))

  const requestBody = {
    campaign_id: "123",
    call_id: "456",
    speaker: "John Doe",
    name: "audio-file.mp3",
  };

  const { error } = await supabaseAdmin.functions.invoke('stt', {
    body: requestBody
  });

  const errorMessage = await error.context.json();

  assertEquals(error.context.status, 400);
  assertEquals(errorMessage.error, 'Object not found');
  assert(stubFrom.withArgs('campaigns').calledOnce) // <- Throw assertion error here, the stub method hasn't been called ??
}

Deno.test("should handle no campaigns found", testNoCampaigns);

See my last assert, that throws an error.
I'm basing all of that on https://supabase.com/docs/guides/functions/unit-test.
Once this test is successful, I will have an other test that also raise a StorageApiError, but for the createSignedUrlmethod.
NB: I'm coming from python, so not really used to this "stub" mechanism as everything is just Mock objects.
Do you have any insight and/or ideas to make it work?
Thanks!
